# what hardware is actually necessary for RTAI 4.1?

Tags: rtai

I've been struggling with this for a while, and may be at the point of purchasing a new computer, so I figured I'd check if anyone knew.

In configuring RTAI 4.1 on ubuntu 14.04 with a 3.10.32 kernel (as advised by a few souces, mainly: https://github.com/ahoarau/mekabot)

The two problems we seem to have are: the ram/cpu/motherboard are not ECC compatible, and we have AMD instead of intel chips. There are multiple things (embedded cryptically in a lot of output) that say we need EEC and intel, but this would be a significant investment.

I just needed to check if anyone know before we spend the money, are ECC memory and intel chip sets absolutely necessary for RTAI 4.1?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that using the exact requirements would be a good way to go, so that  you could have maximum stability on your system. You could also try to run RTAI on you AMD/non ECC systems. Before buying The processors and ECC ram

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that it won't work, no matter what we have tried to do. Since I don't know any RTAI experts, I'm still not sure if it's a configuration problem or if these parts are 100% necessary for it to work at all